# Understanding LSTM through example

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to code up one time step in a LSTM. My focus is on understanding the functioning of the **forget gate layer**, **input gate layer**, **candidate values**, **present** and **future** **cell states**.

Lets assume that my hidden state at t-1 and xt are the following. For simplicity, lets assume that the weight matrices are identity matrices, and  all biases are zero.

```
htminus1 = np.array( [0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6] )
xt = np.array( [-0.1, 0.3, 0.1, -0.25, 0.1] )
```

I understand that forget state is sigmoid of `htminus1` and `xt`

So, is it?

```
ft = 1 / ( 1 + np.exp( -( htminus1 + xt ) ) )

>> ft = array([0.47502081, 0.68997448, 0.549834  , 0.4875026 , 0.66818777])
```

I am referring to [this link](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) to implement of one iteration of one block LSTM. The link says that `ft` should be 0 or 1. Am I missing something here?

**How do I get the forget gate layer as per schema given in the below mentioned picture? An example will be illustrative for me.**

[image]

Along the same lines, **how do I get the input gate layer, `it` and vector of new candidate values, `\tilde{C}_t` as per the following picture?**

[image]

Finally, **how do I get the new hidden state `ht` as per the scheme given in the following picture?**

A simple, example will be helpful for me in understanding. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: why did you not include the weight matrix, how did you/intend to initialize the weights?

Comment: For simplicity, lets assume that the weight matrix is an identity matrix, and bias is zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is not obvious from the figures, but here is how it works -

1. If you see two lines joining to form a single line, it's a concatenation operation. You have interpreted it as an addition.
2. Wherever you see `sigmoid` or `tanh` blocks, a multiplication with a trainable weight matrix is implied.
3. If two lines are joined by an explicit `x` or `+`, you are doing element wise multiplication and addition respectively.

So instead of `sigmoid(htminus1+xt)`, which is what you have, the correct operation would be `sigmoid(Wf * np.concatenate(htminus1+xt)) + bf`. `Wf` is the matrix of trainable parameters and `bf` is the corresponding bias terms.

Note that I have just written the equations on the right side of the images in numpy, not much else. Interpret `[a, b]` as the concetenation operations between `a` and `b`.

You can define the other operations similarly.

```
ft = sigmoid(Wf * np.concatenate(htminus1, xt)) + bf
it = sigmoid(Wi * np.concatenate(htminus1, xt)) + bi
Ctt = tanh(Wc * np.concatenate(htminus1, xt)) + bc
Ot = sigmoid(Wo * np.concatenate(htminus1, xt)) + bo

Ct = (C_{t-1} * ft) + (Ctt * it)
ht = Ot * tanh(Ct)
```

Note: I have represented `C^{tilda}` as `Ctt`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is helpful. Even after concatenation, how can we get only 0 or 1 in the forget gate?

Comment: Could you point me towards where exactly in the blog it says that the forget gate should be 0 or 1? Because as far as I am aware, it should be between 0 and 1, which is exactly what the sigmoid gives.

Comment: You can't get _only_ 0 or 1 in the forget gate: the sigmoid outputs a value between [0,1]. After training your weights this gate will output very close to 1 when the forget gate gets triggered.

Comment: Ananda, Inigo : Got it. It says between [0,1]. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the details already covered, I would like to shed light on some finer aspects of the calculations and the concatenation taking place.

The weight matrix `W_f` is in fact composed of two weight matrices which are concatenated side-by-side i.e. along axis=1 with each weight matrix dealing with previous time step activation(`htminus1`) and current input(`xt`). Whereas, the notation `[htminus1, xt]` denotes a matrix obtained upon concatenating `htminus1` and `xt` vertically by stacking i.e. along axis=0.

These matrix calculations ignoring the bias can be represented like this-
[image: LSTM matrix calculations]

It is also informative to know how these calculations are taking place in tensorflow LSTM model. The code block that follows only contains the main calculations relevant to be discussed here, for the complete code follow this [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/5a7a789ee9766b6a594bd4be8b9edb34e71d6500/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1689)

```py
# gate layers calculations on current inputs
x_i = K.dot ( inputs_i , self.kernel_i )
x_f = K.dot ( inputs_f , self.kernel_f )
x_c = K.dot ( inputs_c , self.kernel_c )
x_o = K.dot ( inputs_o , self.kernel_o )

# adding biases
if self.use_bias :
  x_i = K.bias_add ( x_i , self.bias_i)
  x_f = K.bias_add ( x_f , self.bias_f)
  x_c = K.bias_add ( x_c , self.bias_c)
  x_o = K.bias_add ( x_o , self.bias_o)

# gate layers calculations using previous output ---> h_tm1 i.e htminus1
i = self.recurrent_activation (x_i + K.dot(h_tm1 , self.recurrent_kernel_i) )
f = self.recurrent_activation (x_f + K . dot( h_tm1 , self.recurrent_kernel_f) )
c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation (x_c + K.dot(h_tm1, self.recurrent_kernel_c) )
o = self.recurrent_activation (x_o + K.dot(h_tm1 , self.recurrent_kernel_o) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget gate is clearly explained in this picture

[image: Forget Gate]

.refer ct-1 as at-1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).